# Convert HH:SS Time format to Hours and seconds

Tags: android, time

This seems easy job but I can't figure out how to do this. I'm getting Two time, one from System time ie,

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String currentTimeString = sdf.format(d);
```

and another time from dataset in format of HH:MM. now what I want is subtract it with other one,

```
Double TimeDiff=Double.parseDouble(currentTimeString)-Double.parseDouble(timeLineModel.getmTime());
```

now, this showing error. I am guessing I need convert `Time format` to hours and minutes first then subtract it. Any help of how to it would be appreciated!

Comment: for time Operation, use the java.util.calendar

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(d);
date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(timeLineModel.getmTime());

long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 
days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));  
hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60)); 
min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);
hours = (hours < 0 ? -hours : hours);
```